# Are there any datasets for protectionism?

Tags: data-request, international-trade

Are there any data sources or variables that measure how protectionist a country is? If so, what are they?

Comment: Yes, there are. Did you search online? For example, http://www.iccwbo.org/global-influence/g20/reports-and-products/open-markets-index/ has an openness to trade index. WTO, World Bank and similar organizations collect this data.

Comment: Do any of these organizations have these data for a large number of country-years? I'm doing time series cross-sectional work.

Comment: @SanderHeinsalu good sources. you could include elaborate and turn into an answer.

Comment: There is some research about trade restrictiveness, for example: http://siteresources.worldbank.org/INTRES/Resources/469232-1107449512766/ecoj_2209.pdf
Also here: http://econ.worldbank.org/WBSITE/EXTERNAL/EXTDEC/EXTRESEARCH/0,,contentMDK:22574446~pagePK:64214825~piPK:64214943~theSitePK:469382,00.html

Not sure, but I think it's based on tariff-data and such... 

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Looked a bit further, I think I possibly found what you're looking for:

The Overall Trade Restrictiveness Index (OTRI) summarizes the trade policy stance of a country by calculating the uniform tariff that will keep its overall imports at the current level when the country in fact has different tariffs for different goods.

The data:
http://siteresources.worldbank.org/INTRES/Resources/469232-1107449512766/OTRI2009.xlsx

Background: http://econ.worldbank.org/WBSITE/EXTERNAL/EXTDEC/EXTRESEARCH/0,,contentMDK:22574446~pagePK:64214825~piPK:64214943~theSitePK:469382,00.html

hope this helps,
best regards

Answer (score 0):

Another useful World Bank data set on protectionism is the **Temporary Trade Barriers Database** (TTBD)

The [TTBD website](http://econ.worldbank.org/WBSITE/EXTERNAL/EXTDEC/EXTRESEARCH/EXTPROGRAMS/EXTTRADERESEARCH/0,,contentMDK:22561572~pagePK:64168182~piPK:64168060~theSitePK:544849,00.html) hosts newly collected, freely available, and detailed data on more than thirty different national governments' use of policies such as antidumping (AD), global safeguards (SG), China-specific transitional safeguard (CSG) measures, and countervailing duties (CVD).